# MVC Bundling and Minification - Control the token/version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, minify, bundles

I know that when using the ASP.NET MVC 4 it creates a "bundled" collection of the requested files. I also understand that it adds on a version to the end of the collection URL.

I am wondering if it is possible to change or control the generated token?

`<script src="/Scripts/test?v=8HZAB6C8ZnrIPYNFzMQKt0AR4AUsUYBjxPPkbGSRIZo1" type="text/javascript"></script>`

to become...

`<script src="/Scripts/test?v=1.2" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible from what i have been looking at.